# Wemos D1 Mini deep sleep

Tags: esp8266, sleep

I am building a very simple battery powered touch button using a Wemos D1 Mini (it is basically an ESP8266) and a capacitive touch sensor (something like this: https://www.az-delivery.de/en/products/touch-sensor-modul-1).

Since it is battery powered, I need to reduce as much as possible to consumption of the Wemos D1 Mini. I learnt that, in order to obtain minimum power consumption, we need to use the deep sleep mode. In order to do that, we need to connect RST to D0 (being D0 the WAKE PIN) and program the device accordingly.

My question is: will the Wemos D1 Mini wake up when the touch button is activated (aka: when PIN D1 is pulled up)?

---

Could this be the solution? I could use this as a switch to reset the Wemos D1 Mini and program it to send certain instructions when woken up.

https://youtube.com/watch?v=ojcwgxWMAo8

Comment: Why not try it to find out?

Comment: it will not. deep sleep is complete off. wake-up from deep sleep is a reset.

Comment: it would be far better to power the ESP from the button, perhaps though a mosfet. This will enable the button to work for years on the same battery.

Comment: @dandavis could you elaborate, please? Seems like an interesting solution

Comment: Please do not post further queries as "answers". This isn't a forum. If you want to add more detail to your question, please edit it. I have moved your "answer" into your question.